# getting past RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type ... has been deleted

Tags: python, python-3.x, combobox, pyqt5

When the loops are triggered for the first time, I store the combobox created in a list to retrieve them during the next trigger.

Going through my program after a few iteration, the runtime error is raised when trying to delete combobox from the grid layout

```
for self.combobox in self.itemlist_group:
    self.combobox.deleteLater()

for i in range(len(liste_X)):
    self.combobox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
    self.grid_group.addWidget(self.combobox, i, 0)
    self.itemlist_group.append(self.combobox)
```

I tried to understand why and used a try/except loop to find, and by iterating in the list of combobox, they were still there, but the error is still raised.
The print() returned <class 'PyQt5.QtWidgets.QComboBox'>

I also tried using sip.isdeleted without success...

```
try:
    for self.combobox in self.itemlist_group:
        self.combobox.deleteLater()
    
    for i in range(len(liste_X)):
        self.combobox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.grid_group.addWidget(self.combobox, i, 0)
        self.itemlist_group.append(self.combobox)    
except RuntimeError:
    for self.combobox in self.itemlist_group:
        print(type(self.combobox))
```

Comment: `self.combobox` is not needed, just `for combobox in self.itemlist_group:`

Comment: True ! But it is used later in the program

Comment: @mathieue. you're not removing the widgets from the list when you delete them, and a deleted QObject cannot be used as such (the fact that it's python reference still exists is irrelevant). Change to `while self.itemlist_group:` `self.itemlist_group.pop().deleteLater()` or, alternatively, just clear/overwrite the list after deleting the widgets. Besides, storing a reference to the last element of a loop as an instance attribute is quite odd, especially considering that you also have a list that allows you to access it anyway: if you really need the last combo within the function, that's wrong.

Comment: @mathieue. and if you need it in *another* function, that's probably unreliable anyway, not to mention unsafe, as that would just be an assumption that could potentially recreate the issue once more.

Comment: Thank you for the solution ! I just need to read the content in the other function, but the runtime error would make it impossible to read the content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the solution of Musicamante, the solution is with the while loop:

```
while self.itemlist_group: self.itemlist_group.pop().deleteLater()
```

instead of the first loop:

```
for self.combobox in self.itemlist_group: self.combobox.deleteLater()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).